# Garage Band takes 46 GB?

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-space, garageband, logic

I recently got a new MacBook Pro and it only has 120 GB on it. On the system information page, I saw that garage band takes a whooping 46 GB on my Mac! I don't know how this has happened!

When I received this computer, I installed logic pro, and downloaded a ton of loops. Afterwards, I wanted to delete them for other stuff, so I deleted garageband and logic off my computer, and removed all files and audio loops from application support and elsewhere, however, it still shows that it takes 46 GB. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually garageband taking up that space, but since it shares internal system locations and data, the space used gets categorized as "garageband". The actual space usage is probably due to the audio sample storage, which doesn't have anything to do with the apps but is merely a directory in one of the Library directories (i.e. Your local user Library or the system Library.

Comment: ok thx, but I cant seem to find any folders with high gb, they are all usually 1.02 gb, or 23 mb. Is there a app that helps you sort folders from largest to smallest?

Comment: Yes, try DiskInventoryX, it is a bit old but works fine